# Test a USB-drive/SSD for bad sectors/blocks?

Tags: usb, hardware, ssd

A pretty expensive (Samsung) USB-drive I have causes weird errors. The problem might be a computer I have connected it to (this computer's SSD broke down in a similar way) but to rule out that it is this USB stick that is broken I would like to perform a hardware test on it. How can I do that on a Mac?

Comment: did you try using the Disk Utility in your utility folder

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Yes I have "Erased" it using DU but as far as I know that doesn't include a "quality check", it just writes a new partition table.

Comment: it is called First Aid in DU

Comment: But that just tests the file system, not the hardware, doesn't it?

Comment: how do you test hardware ? in testing the disk consistency

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the Terminal.app in Applications/Utilities.

Cut and paste this inside to install Brew:
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Install e2fsprogs with brew:
`brew install e2fsprogs`

Type `diskutil list` to find your device (/dev/diskX)

Run `badblocks` on your device: (replace the X with your device number)

`/usr/local/Cellar/e2fsprogs/1.44.3/sbin/badblocks -v /dev/diskX`

Comment: e2fsprogs was also available in MacPorts (which I use).

Comment: On newer Brew version it is located at `/opt/homebrew/opt/e2fsprogs/sbin/badblocks`